# What does a vector of vectors look like?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm just getting started with vectors. From what I know, to declare a vector of characters called sentences with a size of 60 it would look like "`vector < char >Ages(60);`"

But what if I was trying to make a vector of sentences (same as above) called pages with an initial size of 50.

Would it look like "`vector< char >pages(50, vector< char >sentences(60))`"?

And then a vector of a vector of a vector, for example, a vector of pages called book with an initial size of 0.

Attempt: `vector < char > book(0, vector< char> book(50, vector< char> sentences(60)))`

I'm confused about the syntax.

Comment: vector<vector<char>> Page(60). since vector<char> represents sentences, vector<sentence> attempts to represent page

Comment: I also want to add a pedantic syntax note: some (I can't speak for all although I suspect this is true) c++ compilers require a space between closing angle brackets when you're nesting types. So the compiler-friendly syntax is ``vector<vector<char> > Page(60)``

Comment: All C++ compilers conforming to standards prior to C++11 require the space, due to the language authors' concerns about how to parse `>>`.  With C++11 and later, `vector<vector<char>>` is legal and much prettier in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

`vector<Type>` creates a `vector` of `Type` objects. So, a `vector` of a `vector` of `Type`, would be `vector<vector<Type>>`. The constructor you are using for `vector<Type>` takes a `size_t` and a default `Type`. If you want to make a `vector` of a `vector` with size `50`, while the innermost `vector`s have size `60`, you would do

```
vector<vector<Type>>(50, vector<Type>(60));
                     ^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                 (size_t)  (default vector<Type> value)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other posters are correct--simply nest whatever you want inside the `<>` brackets. You can go deeper:

```
vector< vector< vector< char > > > Book;
```

Furthermore, it's worth noting that one of the primary advantages of vectors over arrays is that there is no need to specify a size up front. Unless you have a very specific case, just let C++ manage the size for you.